# iPhone Distribution profile with Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, profile, provisioning

I know my distribution profile shouldn't work with my phone, but should it work with the simulator?

My app runs fine in debug on the phone and on the simulator, but then when I run with my distribution profile on the simulator I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the line:

```
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

If I comment this line out then the application starts and stays running with a blank screen. This leads me to thing that the profile should work with the simulator. So why am I getting different results from the different profile??

thanks

Eds

Comment: what do you mean by different profiles? Do you set different targets? The simulator doesn't use any provisioning profile.

Comment: oh ok. Thent this very strange. Basically, if I select my debug profile and then run on simulator, it is fine. If I select my distribution profile then it crashes as above.

Answer (score 0):

you might have release the viewcontroller after
       [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];

Comment: the debugger shows it crashing on that line. So releasing after wouldnt make a difference, would it? Also it works with my debug profile ??

Comment: it make difference in my case...that's why error EXC_BAD_ACCESS because you are using resource that is already released.
it will be good if u post some code

Comment: ok. will post code this evening. Why does it work fine on my debug profile though? It is not being released on that profile. Just when I use the distribution profile